# Debugging AllAuth: social account not logging user in despite connecting successfully

Tags: javascript, django, facebook, django-allauth

Clicking the facebook login button in the login form correctly brings up the fb login popup, but after entering credentials the pop-up closes and nothing happens.

Clicking the button again without reloading the pages confirms that the fb account is connected as browser console prints:

> FB.login() called when user is already connected.

However no new entries appear in the user database, the user isn't redirected and is not signed in.  So the problem appears to be with how AllAuth is handling things.  There's no debug info appearing anywhere on the back-end though, making this somewhat difficult to figure out.

Here's the allauth settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "[removed for stackoverflow]"

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'facebook':
       {'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email','public_profile', 'user_friends'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'verified',
            'locale',
            'timezone',
            'link',
            'updated_time'],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v2.4'}}
```

and this is the js on the login page:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '[removed for stackoverflow]',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: I guess there is no need to add any kind of script in your login page. and also i can see there are some settings missing in your code, check my answer, i have posted whole set of settings required to integrate facebook login into your web-app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Django-allauth Facebook Login

First, install django-allauth

```
$(venv) pip3 install django-allauth
```

now put these code on your installed apps in settings.py

```
'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
```

Also, put code below to your settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Also put these in the settings.py

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'facebook':
       {'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email','public_profile', 'user_friends'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'verified',
            'locale',
            'timezone',
            'link',
            'gender',
            'updated_time'],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'kr_KR',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v2.4'}}
```

> ID and Key can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/ create an
>   app and go to DashBoard, you’ll see your’s

```
#facebook
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'secret!'  # App ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET ='secret!' #app key
```

You might want to add this

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/" 
#if you succeed in login, you'll be redirected to the main page.
```

Now we need to modify the urls.py Add this code to your urlpatterens

```
url(r'^accounts/',include('allauth.urls')),
```

> Now go back to https://developers.facebook.com/ go to settings ,click
>   “Add platform”, click website, put http://localhost:8000/ and click
>   the quick start button. keep going and do what dev.facebook leads to.

Now you need to set your site id in settings.py

```
#site id
SITE_ID = <your local host site id> #i.e http://localhost:8000
# for the dev mode, you need to use localhost's id facebook does not support the name 127.0.0.1:8000
#little options for your page's signup.
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
```

We need to register our site ID and Social application in our django admin
First do migration & runserver

```
$(venv) python3 manage.py migrate
```

go to http://localhost:8000/admin/ and click site ID
change example.com to http://localhost:8000 ( if you are already at production level , you might just use your page’s IP or domain.)

[image]

After saving the application, we are ready to login with facebook.
Put these templates tags to top of a html where you want make your users to login.

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
```

and you can write this exact position where you want to make login button

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Login Button image</a>
```

This send your request to accounts/login page which handles your login procedures.

> Reference:
>   https://medium.com/@jinkwon711/django-allauth-facebook-login-b536444cbc6b

Comment: Nice answer, since Facebook requires https now, it's better to set `ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'`