# Implement Facebook Log In with Django

Tags: django, facebook

Hi I would really appreciate if somebody could please paste there code here for there Facebook login created for their Django project, whether it is a separate app or not, with a couple of explanations. Pulling User Name, Email and profile pic. Thank you

Comment: There is lots of libraries available for social auth in django. If you google it you will find some on github

Comment: refer this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html) may be helps you

Comment: Thanks I was hoping not to use third party app. Have you used social-auth-app-django or django-allAuth yourselves?

Comment: And do they integrate with an existing email login system?

Comment: You can read the source code of the `django-allauth` to see how it can be solved. You need to register an app with facebook, to have a callback url in your app, to persist the auth tokens received by facebook and use them to authenticate the proper django user. It's possible to do all of that yourself, but you'll save a lot of work by using a production-tested third party app.

Comment: In any case you have to register your app with facebook. But that part is fairly straightforward.

Comment: you can refer to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001809/debugging-allauth-social-account-not-logging-user-in-despite-connecting-success/46049491#46049491

Comment: See answer below. No third party apps and works like a charm. If anyone feels like giving an upvote would be nice to be 'unbanned' again from stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

It took me a week but I have implemented Facebook login the hard way. If you don't want a 3rd party app on your site (more secure and trustworthy for users) here are the steps:

1. Get the FB login button here: (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button). You can change the settings of the button before you copy the code.
2. Get the javascript plugin here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web). I suggest copying the example and modifying the following:

Javascript:

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
     FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name, email'}, function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById("your_name2").value = response.name;
      document.getElementById("your_email").value = response.email;
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + response.email + '!';});
```

Once logged in and 'connected' you need to change the info you call. Add the `{fields...}` you require above. Keep the log to see if it's working.

3. Submit the info pulled in 2 into a hidden form in order to send it to a view and model. Here is the form (hellls just default value):

Form template:

```
<form action="{% url 'facebooklogin:register' %}" method="post" style="display: none;" id="myForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
    <input id="your_name2" type="text" name="your_name" value="helllllls">
    <input id="your_email" type="text" name="your_email" value="helllllls">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

4. Set up your form, model and view to handle the information as you want. Get profile pic but simply adding an ImageField to form.

URL:

```
url(r'^registerfb/$', views.get_name, name='register')
```

VIEW:

```
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            logger.error('Form is valid and running')
            logger.error(request.POST.get('your_name'))
            logger.error(request.POST.get('your_email'))
            # redirect to a new URL:

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'facebooklogin/name.html', {'form': form})
```

FORM:

```
class NameForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FBUser
        fields = ['your_name', 'your_email',]
```

Comment: I was using the django-social package for several months.  About two days ago it stopped working. After googling and upgrading, its still not working. I'm going to try this; thank you, I hope it works.

Comment: Sure, I may have made a couple mods since this but works perfectly.