# facebook app can not find my localserver redirected url

Tags: php, python, html, django, facebook

I working on third party social login facebook by using **django-social-auth**package. But when try to login bellow error show . 
I also use django-allauth package and for that i use answerme facebook app.But same problem shown there also.
[image: This error shown when i try to login]
[image: use localserver so domain is localhost]

[image: django-allauth in answerme facebook app][image: site url]

[image: redirecte_url]

Comment: you will find your answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001809/debugging-allauth-social-account-not-logging-user-in-despite-connecting-success/46049491#46049491

Comment: Please supply the error messages as text.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook server will never find your local server because your website is not live and if you are running localserver then that means that is available to you only and the other person or Machine will not be able to access your server which local. so, to provide your url as callback url you will have to host your local server somewhere globally so, that Facebook can go through that and give results in response to that.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings -> basic set `http://localhost:8000/`
In Django settings set:
    `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = your key`
    `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = your secret key`

Also in case of success or fail you can redirect the user using this settings.

For finish `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`
For fail `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL`